# Get the sum of a table's column in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

i have two python files:

1.create_account.py
2.run_sums.py

i want to get the sum of the column balance from the account table by using the sum_balance function.

However every time when i run the run_sums.py i always got the error:

"'int' object is not callable". Anything wrong in my coding?

I am fresh to the sqlalchemy.

create_account.py:

```py
import time
import random
from db_connect import get_conn

conn = get_conn().raw_connection()
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS account")
cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE account(
    id INT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    branch INT NOT NULL,
    balance FLOAT NOT NULL)
""")

for i in xrange(0, 100000):
    account = random.randint(1, 20)
    balance = round(random.uniform(0, 100000), 2)
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO account VALUES (DEFAULT, %d,%f)""" % (account, balance))

conn.commit()
```

run_sums.py:

```py
import argparse
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import time
from db_connect import get_conn
from sqlalchemy import *
from create_account import account

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('S', type = int, help = 'number of sums')
parser.add_argument('I', help = 'isolation level')
args = parser.parse_args()

## Execute a sum query and return the results
def sum_balance(sess):
    ## 1. Execute a query that sum the balance of all accounts.
    ## 2. Fetch the result and return it. 
    acc = account()
    sum_balance = sess.query(func.sum(acc.balance))
    return sum_balance

## Create S sums operations
def S_sums(sess, S):
    sums = []
    start = time.time()

    for i in xrange(0, S):
        while True:
            try:
                sum = sum_balance(sess)
                sums.append(sum)
            except Exception as e:
                print e
                continue
            break

    stop = time.time()
    return sums, stop-start

## Create the engine and run the sums
engine = get_conn()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine.execution_options(isolation_level=args.I, autocommit=True))
sess = Session()
sums, time = S_sums(sess, args.S)
print sums
```

Comment: Could you post the error log?

Comment: it is like: 
'int' object is not callable
'int' object is not callable
'int' object is not callable
'int' object is not callable
'int' object is^C
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_sums.py", line 46, in <module>
    sums, time = S_sums(sess, args.S)
  File "run_sums.py", line 35, in S_sums
    print e

Comment: You're using `sum_balance` both as a name of a variable and a name of a function. Change either and then it should work.

Comment: the variable name is a problem. i have changed it different from the function name. but the problem is still there: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: I can't see where else could the issue be. Please post the updated code and the new error log.

Comment: As an aside, please avoid using the `%` string formatting operator to pass arguments to SQL queries, and use your driver's placeholders instead. Also please post the entire traceback, not just the error message.